# Ruby code to extract data from irregular text with intelligence

Tags: ruby, parsing, extract, text-parsing

I am trying to write a ruby code to extract data from specific location from irregular text content.

The following is the text content something I am looking at.

```
                 Address1                                                   Address2                                       

 adress1, adress1, # 34 , adress1, 
 4th Floor, Plot # 14 & 15, 
 Drive,,                                                               HARIKA BHIMANI

 Madhapur, Hyderabad - 500081                                          2-14-117/35-1 Nas                   
 Andhra Pradesh                                                        AP                                                 
 +(91)40-00000000
 xyz@dabc.com
```

This is my weird text and I want to extract Address1 and Address2 separately. 
I thought I will try split but did not get how to extract Address1 and Address2 separately since both of them are in the single line. The space between content of Address1 and Address2 will be more than 2 space for sure.

I am planning to parse each line and split string in each line with separator more than 1 space. How do split the string in ruby with separator character more than two space ?

We can ignore the first 2 lines in the above text and start from 3rd line. Basically I want to separate out left side and right side data. The separator is more than 2 spaces. I have edited the question with my sample coding but it is failing if one of the line in the left side data is empty

I have tried following sample

```
if !line.empty?

                splits =  line.split(/ {2,}/)

                case splits.length
                    when 2
                        puts "Address1 "+ splits[1]
                    when 3
                        puts "Address1 "+ splits[1]
                        puts "Address2 "+ splits[2] 
                    else

                end
            end
```

But it fails for the following sample

```
   leftSideHasData                    rightSideHasData
                                   OnlyRightSideHasData
```

How can I achieve this in Ruby ? Does ruby provide any apis to do this with ease ?

Comment: you need to be able to confirm that the text would follow a particular pattern, if you can I can help you parse it, else...

Comment: Can you ensure the white spaces at the top is consistent with the rest of the column beneath them.

Comment: Hi We can ignore the first 2 lines in the above text and start from 3rd line. Basically I want to separate out left side and right side data. The separator is more than 2 spaces. I have edited the question with my sample coding but it is failing if one of the line in the left side data is empty

Answer (score 0):

`text = %W{                 Address1                                                   Address2`

adress1, adress1, # 34 , adress1, 
 4th Floor, Plot # 14 & 15, 
 Drive,,                                                               HARIKA BHIMANI

Madhapur, Hyderabad - 500081                                          2-14-117/35-1 Nas
 Andhra Pradesh                                                        AP
 +(91)40-00000000
 xyz@dabc.com}

```
rows = text.split("\n").map { |row| row.split(/\s{2,}/) }

rows.each { |row| address1 << row[0]; address2 << row[1] }

address1
=> ["",
" adress1, adress1, # 34 , adress1, ",
" 4th Floor, Plot # 14 & 15, ",
" Drive,,",
" Madhapur, Hyderabad - 500081",
" Andhra Pradesh",
" +(91)40-00000000",
" xyz@dabc.com"]
```

address2
   => ["Address1", nil, nil, "HARIKA BHIMANI", "2-14-117/35-1 Nas", "AP", nil, nil]

You can remove nils with `address2.compact`

Comment: Hi bjhaid
How can we address the failed case I had put in the question ? If we only have rightSideData, then only row[0] will have the data with string  OnlyRightSideHasData. But with your code this goes to address1 list. And also the input to my data will be line by line. Hence I had tried and posted the sample snippet above but I am straggling to get one case right where line contains only RightSideData.

Comment: Are you reading the text from a file,  if yes can you post a link to a sample??

Comment: No. I am using ruby pdf-reader gem to extract the text by calling reader.page.text and then splitting the entire text content by separator '\n' and parsing each line